# mybatis mapper factory bean and aop

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am developing a web application with mybatis 3,
Spring 3.1.1-RELEASE.
I am referring [the documentation](http://mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html).

None of the Data Access Layer objects created by `MapperFactoryBean` can be pointed as a pointcut of AOP.

I coded spring configuration like this:

```
<bean id="memberDao" name="memberDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
            <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.musicovery.bookervery.dao.MemberDao" />
            <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
        </bean>

<!-- AOP Aspect -->
<bean id="customSqlExceptionTranslator" class="com.musicovery.bookervery.service.exception.CustomSqlExceptionTranslator" />

<!-- AOP Configuration -->
<aop:config>
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="customSqlExceptionTranslator" pointcut="bean(memberDao)" />
        </aop:config>
```

With this configuration,
Eclipse does not show a pointcut-mark of AOP

[image: mark]

When I configure the pointcut to another bean, it works.
But just the objects created by `MapperFactoryBean`.

**I want to apply AOP with Data Access Layer Objects provided from MapperFactoryBean.**

How do I solve this ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

(1)pointcut to the com.musicovery.bookervery.dao.MemberDao , not the MapperFactoryBean.
(2)the MapperFactoryBean is the adapter which spring use to wrapper mybatis mapper to spring bean.

so you can do like this to achieve the transaction aop:

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="txPointcut"
                      expression="execution(public * com.musicovery.bookervery.dao.*.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="txPointcut" advice-ref="txAdvice"/>
</aop:config>
```